# $A$ and $B$ are different matrices satisfying $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I found the following problem interesting but do not know how to tackle it.

> If $A$ and $B$ are different  matrices satisfying $A^3=B^3$ and $A^2B=B^2A$.Then find $\det (A^2+B^2)=?.$

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $(A^2+B^2)(A-B)=A^3-A^2B+B^2A-B^3=0_n.$ Since $A \neq B,$ this shows that  $A^2+B^2$ has a zero divisor.Hence it 
is not invertible. So its determinant is $0.$

Comment: I think it is better to say "_is_ a zero divisor".

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$A^3-A^2B+AB^2-B^3=(A^2-B^2)(A+B) $$